# How to change the y axis on MGCV GAM factor plots?

Tags: r, plot, gam, mgcv

I'd like to adjust the y limits on plots of GAM smoothing functions and factors to more easily compare the effects of two different GAM models for different seasons. When using the `ylim` option in the `plot.gam` function, I am only able to alter the y-axis on the smoothing function but not in the factors.

For example:

```
library(mgcv)
data(cars)
Gam1 <- gam(Price~s(Mileage)+factor(Cylinder), data=cars, family="gaussian")

plot.gam(Gam1, shade=T, pages=1, all.terms=T, rug=FALSE)
plot.gam(Gam1, shade=T, pages=1, ylim=c(-8000,8000), all.terms=T, rug=FALSE)
```

In the second plot, only the y-limits on the smoother change but not on the factor. What's going on here and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see `plot.gam()` code, it is difficult to realize. I think you'd better draw two plots separately by using `plot()` and `termplot()`.

```
library(caret); library(mgcv)
data(cars)
Gam1 <- gam(Price ~ s(Mileage) + as.factor(Cylinder), data=cars, family="gaussian")

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(Gam1, shade=T, all.terms=F, rug=FALSE, ylim=c(-5000, 8000))
termplot(Gam1, se=T, ylim=c(-5000, 30000), ask=F, col.term = 1, col.se = 1)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]